# Importing two matrices from txt file python

Tags: python

I'm trying to import two matrices from a txt file with python. The txt file looks like this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  [7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, None, 13, 15]  [16, 17, 18]
[None, None, None, 19, 20, None]  [21, 22, 23]
[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, None]  [None, None, None]
```

The two matrices are separated by a tab, and have the same number of rows (4 in this example). Every element of a matrix is either an integer of `None`. How can I import them?

This is what I tried so far

```
import numpy
x, y = numpy.loadtxt("file.txt", delimiter="\t")
print(x[0]) # should be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(y[1]) # should be [16, 17, 18]
print(x[0][0] + x[1][0]) # should be 11
```

which gives the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  [7, 8, 9]`. What am I doing wrong?

P.S.
I could create the txt file without the brackets if that helps.

Comment: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  [7, 8, 9]`

Comment: You mentioned you can create the txt file without the brackets. Where are the matrices coming from?

Comment: @R.Arctor The same program.

Comment: @MAO3J1m0Op done.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the braces from your text file and make them comma/space separated lists.

Convert them to fa list of list of floats.

```
results = []
with open("file.txt", "r") a f:
  results.append(f.readline().split(","))
results = [[float(item) for item in result] for result in results]
```

At this stage you've a list of list of floats.
From here you could do a simple

```
np.array_split(results,5)
```

to get two lists and load them into a matrix.

Comment: But the line you're assuming to work is the exact one that raises the error

Comment: But results comes out to be `[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]`, which is just the first line.

Comment: This is what is expected, if you want int, just call int on each item. Then split this list into two using numpy array_split.